# Issues with controlled TreeView (Material UI) shift click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've used the TreeView once before, and shift click worked perfectly to select a range of items. I'm once again building a wrapper of the TreeView component, and this time I'm having issues with the shift click, it simply refuses to do anything. Normal click and control click work fine.

I console logged the array of node ids that gets passed to onNodeSelect and it doesn't have the nodes it should, so it's not a problem with me improperly handling the array of node ids.

Below is the code I'm currently using:

```
const TreeView = ({items = [], folders = []}) => {
    const [highlighted, setHighlighted] = React.useState([]);
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState([]);
    const folderIds = React.useMemo(() => folders.map(folder => folder.id), [folders]);
    const selectNode = (e, arr) => setHighlighted(arr.filter(id => !folderIds.includes(id)));
    const toggleNode = (e, arr) => setExpanded(arr);
    return (
        <MTreeView
            defaultCollapseIcon={<React.Fragment><CollapseIcon/><FolderOpenIcon /></React.Fragment>}
            defaultExpandIcon={<React.Fragment><ExpandIcon/><FolderIcon /></React.Fragment>}
            multiSelect
            onNodeSelect={selectNode}
            selected={highlighted}
            expanded={expanded}
            onNodeToggle={toggleNode}
        >
            {renderFolders(folders,items,"0")}
            {renderItems(items,"0")}
        </MTreeView>
    );
}

const renderFolders = (folders, items,parent) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {folders.filter(folder => folder.parent === parent).map(folder => (
                <TreeItem key={folder.id} nodeId={`${folder.id}`} label={folder.name}>
                    {renderFolders(folders, items, `${folder.id}`)}
                    {renderItems(items, `${folder.id}`)}
                </TreeItem>
            ))}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

const renderItems = (items,parent) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {items.filter(item => item.parent === parent).map(item => (
                <TreeItem key={item.id} nodeId={`${item.id}`} label={item.name} />
            ))}
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Turns out that TreeView does not like having the items wrapped in React Fragments. I posted a Github issue about it [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/21848).